# BackgroundWorker track method from another class

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker

**[EDIT]**

I edited my question with complete code and explanation and hope something can give me clearer explanation.

I have the following Class that has a backgroundworker to track the percentage progress of a loop and update the percentage progress on a Label on ProgressWin's XAML. The following code works perfectly. (My question is far below, after the code.)

```
public partial class ProgressWin : Window
{
    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker1 = new BackgroundWorker();

    public ProgressWin()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeBackgroundWorker();
        startAsync();
    }

    // Set up the BackgroundWorker object by 
    // attaching event handlers. 
    private void InitializeBackgroundWorker()
    {
        backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);
        backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
    }

    private void startAsync()
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    public void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            worker.ReportProgress(i * 10);
        }
    }

    // This event handler updates the progress.
    public void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Content = (e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%");
    }

    // This event handler deals with the results of the background operation.
    public void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
         resultLabel.Content = "Done!";
    }
}
```

Here comes my problem, now instead of tracking the loop within the ProgressWin, I need to track the loop in my MainWindow:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            ????.ReportProgress(i * 10);
        }
    }
}
```

And I have no idea where to go from here. I tried instantiating an object from ProgressWin and call the DoWork but I end up frozen the ProgressWin window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Due to the fact that the question was rewritten, i also rewrote my whole answer.*

To get this to work your `MainWindow`*has a* `ProgressWindow` and should use it like a background worker:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ProgressWindow _Progress;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _Progress = new ProgressWindow();
        _Progress.ProgressChanged += OnProgressChanged;

    }

    private void OnProgressChanged(object sender, ProjectChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //ToDo: Update whatever you like in your MainWindow
    }
}
```

To accomplish this your `ProgressWindow` should simply subscribe to the worker event and rethrow it:

```
public partial class ProgressWin : Window
{
    // Add this to your class above in your question
    public event ProgressChangedEventHandler ProgressChanged;

    // Change or merge this with your existing function
    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProjectChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var temp = ProgressChanged;
        if(temp !=null)
            temp(this, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: is the DoSomething in the MainWindow class and myWorker in the other class? What does "data" come from? And why am I casting data as BackgroundWorder? Sorry I have zero understanding of your answer, could you please elaborate thanks alot.

Comment: I have edited my question, i think it'll make it easier to understand my question..

Answer (score 1):

You can simply call method of another class by doing

`backgroudnWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(SomeClass.SomeStaticMethod);`

or

`backgroudnWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(SomeClassInstance.SomeMethod);`

for calling a method of `MainWindow` class from another class `ProgressScreen` you should have reference of instance of `MainWindow` class in `ProgressScreen` then using that instance you can call any public method of `MainWindow` from `ProgressScreen` class

and as Oliver Said, you will need the instance of `backgroundworker` to send the progress updates from other method.

Comment: Where do I set the instance of backgroundworker, in my MainWindow or my other class? How to I send the progress update.

Comment: You want progress in `ProgressScreen` class right? Create instance of `BackgroudWorker` in that class. Now pass the instance of `BGWorker` as an argument to method which you will call in `DoWork` i.e `TimeConsumingMethod`